# Kubernetes rest api to check if namespace is created and active

Tags: kubernetes

I call the below rest api with post body to create a namespace in kubernetes

http://kuberneteshot/api/v1/namespaces/

```
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "kind": "Namespace",
    "metadata": {
        "name": "testnamespace"
    }
}
```

In response i get the http status 201 created and the below json response

```
{
    "kind": "Namespace",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {
        "name": "testnamespace",
        "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/testnamespace",
        "uid": "701ff75e-5781-11e6-a48a-74dbd1a0fb73",
        "resourceVersion": "57825525",
        "creationTimestamp": "2016-08-01T00:46:52Z",
    },
    "spec": {
        "finalizers": [
            "kubernetes"
        ]
    },
    "status": {
        "phase": "Active"
    }
}
```

Does the status in response with phase as Active mean the namespace is successfully created and active ?

Is there any other rest api to check if the namespace exists and is active ?

The reason i would like to know if the namespace is created is because i get an error message if i fire create pod before the namespace is actually created:

> Error from server: error when creating "./pod.json": pods "my-pod" is
>   forbidden: service account username/default was not found, retry after
>   the service account is created

The below works fine if i give a sleep of 5 seconds between create namespace and create pod command

> kubectl delete namespace testnamepsace;kubectl create namespace
>   testnamepsace;sleep 5;kubectl create -f ./pod.json
>   --namespace=testnamepsace

If i don't give the sleep of 5 seconds i see the error message mentioned above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently your Pod has a hard dependency on the `default` ServiceAccount, so you probably want to check it's been created instead of looking only at the namespace state. The existence of the namespace doesn't guarantee the immediate availability of your `default` ServiceAccount.

Some API endpoints you might want to query:

- GET `/api/v1/namespaces/foo/serviceaccounts/default`
  returns 200 with the object description if the ServiceAccount `default` exists in the namespace `foo`, 404 otherwise
- GET `/api/v1/serviceaccounts?fieldSelector=metadata.namespace=foo,metadata.name=default`
  returns 200 and a list of all ServiceAccount items in the namespace `foo` with name `default` (empty list if no object matches)

Comment: how can i check if the default ServiceAccount is created, is there a rest service i can call to check this ? Thanks.

Comment: I updated my answer with 2 endpoints you could use. You can of course drop the query parameters in the second option to return a list of all ServiceAccount objects in all namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the namespace is persisted prior to being returned from the create API call. The returned object shows the status of the namespace as `Active`.

You can also do `GET http://kubernetehost/api/v1/namespaces/testnamespace` to retrieve the same information.